# Point to a Local git package on bower, with specific branch

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, gruntjs, bower

I'm trying to figure out some things in bower but am having some issues. Mainly, when I try and install a locally hosted repo's specific branch.

For instance, I run this command:

```
bower install appName=/path/to/file
```

However, when I do that, I get:

```
ENORESTARGET Tag/branch master does not exist

Additional error details:
Available tags: some-tag-1,
Available branches: integration, origin/bower
```

I'm specifically trying to get to the 'orgin/bower' branch. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is this a duplicate? the other question is talking about packages hosted in bower, this one is specifically about packages hosted locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
bower install appname=/path/to/file#bower
```

Make sure the path is valid and that it points to a git repo which contains a `bower` branch.

*Also note that `appname` should be lowercase.*

Comment: think it was the case that got me. thanks!